# Constraints syntax a predicate and in an assert

Tags: alloy

I want to know if constraints syntax differs if used in a predicate than in an assert.

The constraint **all disj x1,x2:X | x1 =x2** gives different results when executed in a 
predicate and in an assert.

For example, assume the following model:

```
sig A {}

sig B {x: one A}

assert S1 
{all x1,x2: x | x1 = x2}
```

check S1 for 2 – counterexamples as non equivalent instances of x1 and x2

```
assert S2
{! (all x1,x2: x | x1 = x2)}
```

check S2 for 2 -- higher-order quantification error

```
pred P1 
{(all x1,x2: x | x1 = x2)}

run P1 for 2 -- higher-order quantification error

pred P2
{! (all x1,x2: x | x1 = x2)}
```

run p2 for 2 --generates non equivalent instances of x1 and x2

how come that some constraints are quantifiable while their negation is not and vice versa!

thanks

Abdallah Rayhan

Answer (score 1):

In all 4 of those examples you have a higher-order quantifier: you're trying to quantify over a binary field (`x: A -> B`), so when you say `all x1, x2: x | ...`, it means "for all binary tuples x1 and x2 drawn from the binary relation x".  Alloy is first-order and can't in general handle higher-order stuff.  The reason why it doesn't complain in some of those cases is that it is able to "skolemize" the quantifier, so that it doesn't have to check anything for **all** tuples of arity greater than 1.

For example, when you say `check S1`, you are asking Alloy if it is true that something holds for for all binary tuples; since Alloy is a bounded model-finder, it will try to refute that by finding a **single** such tuple for which the body doesn't hold---there is nothing higher order there, so this case will work.  When you say "check S2", you are asking Alloy if it is not true that something holds for all binary tuples, so to refute that Alloy would actually have to check that the body holds for **every** such binary tuple---that is higher order and Alloy can't do it.

I don't know if your intention was to have this higher-order quantification in the first place.  Just guessing, maybe what you wanted to have was just `all b: B, a: b.x | ...`, which is first-order and will work fine.